# Dependency injection of directive child into parent component

Tags: angular

I was trying to control `audio` element in Angular2 by writing a directive wrapper.

The problem i am facing is with controlling this audio element from it's parent component.

See my [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/j8hti6jtedqnvDMhiKCI?p=preview).

I created a `audio-player` component with template

```
  template: `Audio player 1: <audio  #tick1 src="/static/audio/tick10s.mp3"></audio><br>
            Adio player 2: <audio  #tick2 src="/static/audio/tick10s.mp3"></audio><br>`
```

This creates two directive `MyAudio` one for each `tick1` and `tick2`. I need to control these components from `AudioPlayer` class.

I tried to inject these two directives in `AudioPlayer` using

```
  @ViewChild('tick1') tick1: MyAudio;
  @ViewChild('tick2') tick2: MyAudio;
```

This gives me `ElementRef` object instead of `MyAudio` object.

But this works

`@ViewChildren(MyAudio) children: QueryList<MyAudio>;`

but with this approach i cannot differentiate between the two audio elements.

Any idea why is this happening and how can I get specific `MyAudio` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`exportAs`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DirectiveMetadata-class.html) property, this way the `#tick*` variable will hold a reference to the directive instead of the element.

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'audio',
  exportAs : 'myAudio'
})
```

And then in your template, you assign the property called `myAudio` to the variable corresponding.

```
Audio player 1: <audio  #tick1="myAudio" src="/static/audio/tick10s.mp3"></audio>
Audio player 2: <audio  #tick2="myAudio" src="/static/audio/tick10s.mp3"></audio>
```

Here's your [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NZ3aJzKNhmyxRTDOokCO?p=info) updated and working ;D

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a ton @Eric! I am wondering how this works. The documentation of exportAs is not much useful.